# having trouble json dump variable onto individual lines

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print a json dump onto multiple lines. Currently it is printing on one line.

Here are the steps I am attempting;

Step 1: This is the code that I want to print

```
payload = json.dumps({"ip-detunnel": "No",
                      "name": "DP800 Slot 1",
                      "vlan-tag-insertion": "No",
                      "vlan-tag-remove-forward": "Remove",
                      "mac-replace-header": "No",
                      "mpls-label-stack": "Pass Through"
                      })
```

Step 2: This is how I am trying to print

```
print '\n' + payload
```

Step 3: Here is the Result:

```
{"vlan-tag-insertion": "No", "name": "DP800 Slot 1", "mpls-label-stack": "Pass Through", "vlan-tag-remove-forward": "Remove", "ip-detunnel": "No", "mac-replace-header": "No"}
```

My goal is to print the results on multiple lines so that it looks like the json.dumps in step 1

Answer (score 3):

Pass `indent=4` to `dumps`

```
payload = json.dumps({"ip-detunnel": "No", "name": "DP800 Slot 1", "vlan-tag-insertion": "No", "vlan-tag-remove-forward": "Remove", "mac-replace-header": "No", "mpls-label-stack": "Pass Through" }, indent=4)
```

Or any other number other than 0. Each nesting of the json object will be indented by that many spaces before it. 
Output:

```
>>>print(payload)
{
    "ip-detunnel": "No",
    "name": "DP800 Slot 1",
    "vlan-tag-insertion": "No",
    "vlan-tag-remove-forward": "Remove",
    "mac-replace-header": "No",
    "mpls-label-stack": "Pass Through"
}
```

Comment: I am still having trouble and I get one line return
>payload = json.dumps({"ip-detunnel": "No",\"name": "DP800 Slot 1",         "vlan-tag-insertion": "No",
"vlan-tag-remove-forward": "Remove",
"mac-replace-header": "No",
"mpls-label-stack": "Pass Through"
 })